# Trim an specific HTML tag by PHP

Tags: php, trim

Suppose I have the code below, how can I only remove the HTML tag of `<p>` and `</p>`?

Thanks

```
<p>This is the first line<br /> This is the second line with image <img src="1.jpg" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for the [str_replace](http://php.net/str-replace) function.

*mixed* **str_replace** ( mixed *$search* , mixed *$replace* , mixed *$subject* [, int &*$count* ] )

```
<?php

    $str = '<p>This is the first line<br /> This is the second line with image <img src="1.jpg" /></p>'
    echo str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), NULL, $str);

?>
```

Comment: @CharlesYeung, good good. Feel free to upvote, and hit the check mark next to my answer.